# C# SSH.NET half-duplex raw binary connection

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, .net-5, ssh.net

I'm trying to get half-duplex ssh connection in C#/.NET 5 with SSH.NET for sending protobuf-formatted packets. (Although full-duplex would be nice, I can emulate that using two streams)

So far I'm able to get data back and forth, however with a few caveats:

- I need to send a newline in order to actually commit any info.
- I'm only able to send plain text, sending protobuf-formatted binary data creates weird deserialization errors, probably related to encoding-errors.

Currently I'm trying to use SSH.NETs ShellStream on the client-side and deserializing using ProtoBufs non-generic deserializer, mapping types to indexes with a dict:

```cs
using SshClient client = new(connectionInfo);

var stream = client.CreateShellStream("", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024, new Dictionary<TerminalModes, uint>());

stream.WriteLine("./bin/myProcess");
stream.Expect("Running");

// The stream is now at the point where the packets are supposed to be sent

// Two dicts for mapping types to indicies and back
// Just send strings as packets for now
Dictionary<int, Type> typeByIndex = new { [0] = typeof(string) };
Dictionary<Type, int> indexByType = new { [typeof(string)] = 0 };

// Send a packet over
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(
    stream, "Hello World!",
    PrefixStyle.Base128, indexByType[typeof(string)]);
stream.WriteLine(""); // Write newline to commit and use SSH.NET writing method to directly flush

while (true)
{
    if (Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(
        stream, PrefixStyle.Base128,
        field => typeByIndex[field-1], out var packet)) Console.WriteLine(packet);
}
```

With the server (`./bin/myProcess`) just reading from `Console.OpenStandardInput()` with the same while-loop.

This produces deserialization errors (`Unexpected wire-type` usually). My guess is that this has to do with encoding problems.

Given the not to great documentation of SSH.NET I don't really know what to try here.

To sum up:
How would I configure SSH.NET to allow sending arbitrary protobuf-formatted binary data back and forth (without any kind of encoding conversions or control characters causing issues) and how would I get around having to send a newline with every packet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *sounds* like the Stream it is giving you here is really a wrapper over the text-based console, and doesn't really support arbitrary binary. This is something you should probably ask the package creator - there may be some toggle to enable "binary mode" or similar, but without that - honestly I'm a little surprised it doesn't give you a text-writer/text-reader API instead of a stream.

Worst case, you can base-64 encode the protobuf data, and send that down a text protocol, and reverse it at the other end.

Comment: And in any case, the SSH "shell" channel is not intended for such task. For that one should use "exec" channel. But SSH.NET does not support streaming the "exec" channel unfortunately.

Comment: @Martin ah thanks; so the exec channel is binary and the shell channel is text? useful context, thanks

Comment: It's not that strict. But indeed, the "shell" channel is for interactive human use. And "exec" channel is for command automation. So that kind of implies that the first is text and the latter is binary safe.

Comment: Sounds like what I feared. Thanks, I'll open an issue on their repo

Comment: I've created an issue on their repo [here](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/802) and a hacky workaround [here](https://gist.github.com/blenderfreaky/3d2d03a9af6eaa30ec534437774c779d) that - as far as I understand - goes over the exec channel instead.